# problem with step by step debugging in android

Tags: android

i fairly new to android.
i mostly use Logcat for debugging but some times when the problem gets to evading i use breakpoints.

when i do so, i encounter the following problem:

if i find the mistake and change the mistake while debugging i get a warning message that the vm may not be able to include my changed. i have tried ignoring this warning but the vm does not accept the modified string.

how do i enable to the vm to accept the modified thread?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike desktop Java, you can not enable hot swapping of code with Android development. You will have to reinstall and rerun your application to get the VM to accept the new code.